# How to install SQL Server 2017 Express in "Quiet Simple" mode without an extraction folder?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-express

I need to install SQL Server 2017 Express with as little user interaction as possible. I am using the **SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe** setup file that I found a Microsoft download for. The installer I am currently using is the 2017 CORE one [linked to from here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx) (I have no idea how people find official Microsoft downloads for anything!)

Currently I can do exactly what I want with 2012 by using the following parameters:

```
/FEATURES="SQL, Tools" /QS /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=1 /ACTION="Install" /ERRORREPORTING=0 /INSTANCENAME="MyDB"
```

In 2012 this works great, however I am trying to now do the same in 2017. The problem I have is that it creates an extraction folder called "SQLEXPR_x64_ENU" in the same directory as the install. This is not desirable.

**Question**: Is there anyway to prevent this extraction folder from being used, so that it functions that same as the 2012 setup?

Alternatively, one of the following solutions would be acceptable:

- Allow the user to select the extraction location - like it does with default install (non-quiet) - but still ensure /QS mode for the rest of the setup
- Have the extraction folder automatically deleted after setup (it wouldn't be so bad if it cleaned up it's mess after it was finished)

Comment: why are you using the CORE edition of Express?

Comment: @LowlyDBA: Don't know yet, so far it's just smaller. The same problem occurs with the advanced tools installer too. I will worry about which installer too use later... TBH i am finding it difficult to find any information showing the differences between core and full, do you know any good resource for that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about the core either (some info [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/395525/what-is-sql-server-core-edition) though), but as Luuk mentioned the 'normal' versions have proper parameters for what you're looking for...I'd use that one and save yourself the trouble. It's probably not worth your time to save a few MBs. I've been working with MSSQL for ~10 years and never seen a core installer used.

Comment: @LowlyDBA: Thanks, though I am not sure still. I though "core" was just a stripped down (no extras) version. Literally just the bare minimum db server. Anyway, I have tested the same with the full version and MediaPath doesn't seem to be recognised - using it has no effect. [This is my source for the params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-from-the-command-prompt?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Ah, ok yeah I misread Luuk's answer, that isn't what you want here. You could try [extracting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547809/extract-msi-from-exe) the exe contents to a better location for you/the user and then run the install from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create a PowerShell script to start the install. After the install is finished:

- verify success (possibly with the return code or parsing the output log)
- verify the existence of the extraction folder
- if there are no errors delete the extraction folder

Comment: The installer is bundled in with the installation of other software, so I can't do that exactly... however, it's might be possible we can modify the main installer to do the deletion as part of the process... so, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

/MediaPath=... seems to be the option to be used to specify where the stuff is extracted.

Below is output from `SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe /help`:

```
SQLServer2017-SSEI-Expr.exe [/ENU] [/Help] [/IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms] [/Quiet] [/HideProgressBar] [/Verbose] [/ConfigurationFile=C:\Configuration.ini] [/Action=Install] [/Language=en-US] [/MediaType=Expr] [/InstallPath=c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server] [/MediaPath=C:\SetupMedia]

ACTION                    Indicates the workflow when performing a unattended operation.
                          Allowed Values      : Install, Download
                          Supported Actions   : Any

CONFIGURATIONFILE         Specifies the ConfigurationFile to use.
                          Supported Actions   : Install

ENU                       Use this parameter to install the English version of SQL Server on a localized operating system.
                          Supported Actions   : Any

HELP                      Displays the usage options for unattended operations.
                          Alias               : ?
                          Supported Actions   : Any

HIDEPROGRESSBAR           Indicates a progress bar should not be displayed in an unattended install.
                          Alias               : HP
                          Supported Actions   : Any

IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS Required to acknowledge acceptance of the license terms.
                          Supported Actions   : Install

INSTALLPATH               Specifies the data directory for SQL Server data files.
                          Supported Actions   : Install

LANGUAGE                  Language choice for Install or Download operations.
                          Alias               : Lang
                          Allowed Values      : zh-CN, zh-TW, en-US, fr-FR, de-DE, it-IT, ja-JP, ko-KR, pt-BR, ru-RU, es-ES
                          Supported Actions   : Any

MEDIAPATH                 Location where SQL Server setup media will be downloaded and extracted to.
                          Supported Actions   : Any

MEDIATYPE                 Indicates the type of media to download when /Action=Download
                          Alias               : MT
                          Allowed Values      : Core, Advanced, LocalDB
                          Supported Actions   : Download

QUIET                     Specifies that SQL Server Installer runs in a quiet mode without any user interface. This is used for unattended operations.
                          Alias               : Q
                          Supported Actions   : Any

VERBOSE                   Logs verbose output to the console.
                          Alias               : V
                          Supported Actions   : Any
```

EDIT: With the core version (see link in question), you can extract the download using: `D:\TEMP\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /x`
This will download install files the the location `D:\TEMP\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU\`

`SETUP.EXE /?` gives a bunch of, maybe useful, options:

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server 2017 14.00.1000.169
Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft.  All rights reserved.

SQL Server 2017 transmits information about your installation experience, as well as other usage and performance data, to Microsoft to help improve the product. To learn more about SQL Server 2017 data processing and privacy controls, please see the Privacy Statement.
Usage:
 setup.exe /[option]={value} /[option]={value} ...

 Options:
 ACTION                       Specifies a Setup work flow, like INSTALL,
                              UNINSTALL, or UPGRADE. This is a required
                              parameter.
 ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN     Provision current user as a Database Engine
                              system administrator for %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME%
                              Express.
 AGTDOMAINGROUP               Either domain user name or system account
 AGTSVCACCOUNT                Either domain user name or system account
 AGTSVCPASSWORD               Password for domain user name. Not required for
                              system account
 AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE            Startup type for the SQL Server Agent service.
                              Supported values are Manual, Automatic or
                              Disabled.
 ALLINSTANCES                 Specifies that all instances are to be included
                              in the Setup operation. This parameter is
                              supported only when applying a patch.
 ASBACKUPDIR                  The location for the Analysis Services backup
                              files.
 ASCOLLATION                  The collation used by Analysis Services.
 ASCONFIGDIR                  The location for the Analysis Services
                              configuration files.
 ASDATADIR                    The location for the Analysis Services data
                              files.
 ASLOGDIR                     The location for the Analysis Services log files.
 ASPROVIDERMSOLAP             Specifies if the MSOLAP provider can run in
                              process.
 ASSERVERMODE                 Specifies the server mode of the Analysis
                              Services instance. Valid values are
                              MULTIDIMENSIONAL and TABULAR. The default value
                              is TABULAR.
 ASSVCACCOUNT                 The account used by the Analysis Services
                              service.
 ASSVCPASSWORD                The password for the Analysis Services service
                              account.
 ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE             Controls the service startup type setting for the
                              service.
 ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS           Specifies the list of administrator accounts to
                              provision.
 ASTELSVCACCT                 ASTelemetryUserNameConfigDescription
 ASTELSVCPASSWORD             ASTelemetryPasswordConfigDescription
 ASTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE          ASTelemetryStartupConfigDescription
 ASTEMPDIR                    The location for the Analysis Services temporary
                              files.
 BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE        Startup type for Browser Service.
 CLTCTLRNAME                  The computer name that the client communicates
                              with for the Distributed Replay Controller
                              service.
 CLTRESULTDIR                 The result directory for the Distributed Replay
                              Client service.
 CLTSTARTUPTYPE               The startup type for the Distributed Replay
                              Client service.
 CLTSVCACCOUNT                The account used by the Distributed Replay Client
                              service.
 CLTSVCPASSWORD               The password for the Distributed Replay Client
                              service account.
 CLTWORKINGDIR                The working directory for the Distributed Replay
                              Client service.
 CLUSTERPASSIVE               Specifies that SQL Server Setup should not manage
                              the SQL Server services. This option should be
                              used only in a non-Microsoft cluster environment.
 COMMFABRICENCRYPTION         MATRIXCOMMMESSAGEPROTECTION {0,1}
 COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL       MATRIXCOMMNETWORKISOLATION {0,1}
 COMMFABRICPORT               MATRIXCOMMPORT <port>
 CONFIGURATIONFILE            Specifies the configuration file to be used for
                              Setup.
 CONFIRMIPDEPENDENCYCHANGE    Indicates that the change in IP address resource
                              dependency type for the SQL Server multi-subnet
                              failover cluster is accepted.
 CTLRSTARTUPTYPE              The startup type for the Distributed Replay
                              Controller service.
 CTLRSVCACCOUNT               The account used by the Distributed Replay
                              Controller service.
 CTLRSVCPASSWORD              The password for the Distributed Replay
                              Controller service account.
 CTLRUSERS                    The Windows account(s) used to grant permission
                              to the Distributed Replay Controller service.
 ENABLERANU                   Set to "1" to enable RANU for SQL Server Express.
 ENU                          Use the /ENU parameter to install the English
                              version of SQL Server on your localized Windows
                              operating system.
 EXTSVCACCOUNT                User account for Launchpad Service.
 EXTSVCPASSWORD               User password for Launchpad Service account.
 FAILOVERCLUSTERDISKS         Specifies a cluster shared disk to associate with
                              the SQL Server failover cluster instance.
 FAILOVERCLUSTERGROUP         Specifies the name of the cluster group for the
                              SQL Server failover cluster instance.
 FAILOVERCLUSTERIPADDRESSES   Specifies an encoded IP address. The encodings
                              are semicolon-delimited (;), and follow the
                              format <IP Type>;<address>;<network name>;<subnet
                              mask>. Supported IP types include DHCP, IPV4, and
                              IPV6.
 FAILOVERCLUSTERNETWORKNAME   Specifies the name of the SQ LServer failover
                              cluster instance.  This name is the network name
                              that is used to connect to SQL Server services.
 FAILOVERCLUSTERROLLOWNERSHIP Specifies whether the upgraded nodes should take
                              ownership of the failover instance group or not.
                              Use 0 to retain ownership in the legacy nodes, 1
                              to make the upgraded nodes take ownership, or 2
                              to let SQL Server Setup decide when to move
                              ownership.
 FEATURES                     Specifies features to install, uninstall, or
                              upgrade. The list of top-level features include
                              SQL, AS, IS, MDS, and Tools. The SQL feature will
                              install the Database Engine, Replication,
                              Full-Text, and Data Quality Services (DQS)
                              server. The Tools feature will install shared
                              components.
 FILESTREAMLEVEL              Level to enable FILESTREAM feature at (0, 1, 2 or
                              3).
 FILESTREAMSHARENAME          Name of Windows share to be created for
                              FILESTREAM File I/O.
 FTSVCACCOUNT                 User account for Full-text Filter Daemon Host.
 FTSVCPASSWORD                User password for Full-text Filter Daemon Host
                              account.
 FTUPGRADEOPTION              Full-text catalog upgrade option.
 HELP                         Displays the command line parameters usage
 IACCEPTPYTHONLICENSETERMS    By specifying this parameter and accepting
                              Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R Server terms,
                              you acknowledge that you have read and understood
                              the terms of use.
 IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS     By specifying this parameter and accepting
                              Microsoft R Open and Microsoft R Server terms,
                              you acknowledge that you have read and understood
                              the terms of use.
 IACCEPTRSUNINSTALL           By specifying this parameter, you acknowledge
                              that Reporting Services will be uninstalled and
                              you've performed any necessary backup and/or
                              migration.
 IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS By specifying this parameter and accepting the
                              SQL Server license terms, you acknowledge that
                              you have read and understood the terms of use.
 INDICATEPROGRESS             Specifies that the detailed Setup log should be
                              piped to the console.
 INSTALLSHAREDDIR             Specify the root installation directory for
                              shared components.  This directory remains
                              unchanged after shared components are already
                              installed.
 INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR          Specify the root installation directory for the
                              WOW64 shared components.  This directory remains
                              unchanged after WOW64 shared components are
                              already installed.
 INSTALLSQLDATADIR            The Database Engine root data directory.
 INSTANCEDIR                  Specify the instance root directory.
 INSTANCEID                   Specify the Instance ID for the SQL Server
                              features you have specified. SQL Server directory
                              structure, registry structure, and service names
                              will incorporate the instance ID of the SQL
                              Server instance.
 INSTANCENAME                 Specify a default or named instance. MSSQLSERVER
                              is the default instance for non-Express editions
                              and SQLExpress for Express editions. This
                              parameter is required when installing the SQL
                              Server Database Engine (SQL), or Analysis
                              Services (AS).
 ISMASTERSVCACCOUNT           Either domain user name or system account.
 ISMASTERSVCPASSWORD          Password for domain user.
 ISMASTERSVCPORT              Network port.
 ISMASTERSVCSSLCERTCN         CNs in a SSL certificate, e.g. CN=[MachineName];
                              CN=[IP]
 ISMASTERSVCSTARTUPTYPE       Automatic, Manual or Disabled.
 ISMASTERSVCTHUMBPRINT        Thumbprint of a SSL certificate.
 ISSVCACCOUNT                 Either domain user name or system account.
 ISSVCPASSWORD                Password for domain user.
 ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE             Automatic, Manual or Disabled.
 ISTELSVCACCT                 TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription
 ISTELSVCPASSWORD             TelemetryPasswordConfigDescription
 ISTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE          TelemetryStartupConfigDescription
 ISWORKERSVCACCOUNT           Either domain user name or system account.
 ISWORKERSVCCERT              Path of a certificate file.
 ISWORKERSVCMASTER            Master machine name/ip and port,
                              https://[Name]:[Port] or https://[IP]:[Port].
 ISWORKERSVCPASSWORD          Password for domain user.
 ISWORKERSVCSTARTUPTYPE       Automatic, Manual or Disabled.
 MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT        MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT portNumber
 MATRIXCMSERVERNAME           MATRIXCMSERVERNAME hostName\instanceName
 MATRIXNAME                   MATRIXNAME=<name>
 MRCACHEDIRECTORY             Cache directory for Microsoft R Open and
                              Microsoft R Server.
 NPENABLED                    Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the Named
                              Pipes protocol.
 PBDMSSVCACCOUNT              PolybaseDmsUserNameConfigDescription
 PBDMSSVCPASSWORD             PolybaseDmsPasswordConfigDescription
 PBDMSSVCSTARTUPTYPE          PolybaseDmsStartupConfigDescription
 PBENGSVCACCOUNT              PolybasePdwUserNameConfigDescription
 PBENGSVCPASSWORD             PolybasePdwPasswordConfigDescription
 PBENGSVCSTARTUPTYPE          PolybasePdwStartupConfigDescription
 PBPORTRANGE                  PolybasePortRangeDescription
 PBSCALEOUT                   PolybaseScaleOutDescription
 PID                          Specify the SQL Server product key to configure
                              which edition you would like to use.
 QUIET                        Setup will not display any user interface.
 QUIETSIMPLE                  Setup will display progress only, without any
                              user interaction.
 ROLE                         Detailed help for command line argument ROLE has
                              not been defined yet.
 RSCATALOGSERVERINSTANCENAME  The SQL Server server for the report server
                              catalog database.
 RSINSTALLMODE                Specifies which mode report server is installed
                              in.
                              Default value: "FilesOnly"
 RSSVCACCOUNT                 Specify the service account of the report server.
                              This value is required. If you omit this value,
                              Setup will use the default built-in account for
                              the current operating system (either
                              NetworkService or LocalSystem). If you specify a
                              domain user account, the domain must be under 254
                              characters and the user name must be under 20
                              characters. The account name cannot contain the
                              following characters:
                              " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >
 RSSVCPASSWORD                Specify a strong password for the account. A
                              strong password is at least 8 characters and
                              includes a combination of upper and lower case
                              alphanumeric characters and at least one symbol
                              character. Avoid spelling an actual word or name
                              that might be listed in a dictionary.
 RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE             Specifies the startup mode for the Report Server
                              service. Valid values include Manual, Automatic,
                              and Disabled. The default value for StartupType
                              is Manual, where the server is started when a
                              request is received.
 RULES                        Specifies the list of rule IDs or rule group IDs
                              to run.
 SAPWD                        Password for SQL Server sa account.
 SECURITYMODE                 The default is Windows Authentication. Use "SQL"
                              for Mixed Mode Authentication.
 SQLBACKUPDIR                 Default directory for the Database Engine backup
                              files.
 SQLCOLLATION                 Specifies a Windows collation or an SQL collation
                              to use for the Database Engine.
 SQLSVCACCOUNT                Account for SQL Server service: Domain\User or
                              system account.
 SQLSVCINSTANTFILEINIT        Set to "True" to enable instant file
                              initialization for SQL Server service.
 SQLSVCPASSWORD               A SQL Server service password is required only
                              for a domain account.
 SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE            Startup type for the SQL Server service.
 SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS          Windows account(s) to provision as SQL Server
                              system administrators.
 SQLTELSVCACCT                TelemetryUserNameConfigDescription
 SQLTELSVCPASSWORD            TelemetryPasswordConfigDescription
 SQLTELSVCSTARTUPTYPE         TelemetryStartupConfigDescription
 SQLTEMPDBDIR                 Directories for Database Engine TempDB files.
 SQLTEMPDBFILECOUNT           The number of Database Engine TempDB files.
 SQLTEMPDBFILEGROWTH          Specifies the automatic growth increment of each
                              Database Engine TempDB data file in MB.
 SQLTEMPDBFILESIZE            Specifies the initial size of a Database Engine
                              TempDB data file in MB.
 SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR              Directory for the Database Engine TempDB log
                              files.
 SQLTEMPDBLOGFILEGROWTH       Specifies the automatic growth increment of the
                              Database Engine TempDB log file in MB.
 SQLTEMPDBLOGFILESIZE         Specifies the initial size of the Database Engine
                              TempDB log file in MB.
 SQLUSERDBDIR                 Default directory for the Database Engine user
                              databases.
 SQLUSERDBLOGDIR              Default directory for the Database Engine user
                              database logs.
 SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTI Specifies that SQL Server Setup should not
                              display the privacy statement when ran from the
                              command line.
 TCPENABLED                   Specify 0 to disable or 1 to enable the TCP/IP
                              protocol.
 UIMODE                       Parameter that controls the user interface
                              behavior. Valid values are Normal for the full
                              UI,AutoAdvance for a simplied UI, and
                              EnableUIOnServerCore for bypassing Server Core
                              setup GUI block.
 UpdateEnabled                Specify whether SQL Server Setup should discover
                              and include product updates. The valid values are
                              True and False or 1 and 0. By default SQL Server
                              Setup will include updates that are found.
 UpdateSource                 Specify the location where SQL Server Setup will
                              obtain product updates. The valid values are "MU"
                              to search Microsoft Update, a valid folder path,
                              a relative path such as .\MyUpdates or a UNC
                              share. By default SQL Server Setup will search
                              Microsoft Update or a Windows Update service
                              through the Window Server Update Services.
 USEMICROSOFTUPDATE           If this parameter is provided, then this computer
                              will use Microsoft Update to check for updates.
 X86                          Specifies that Setup should install into WOW64.
                              This command line argument is not supported on an
                              IA64 or a 32-bit system.

Full unattended installation example, showing all required parameters:


setup.exe /Q /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /ACTION=install /PID=<validpid> /FEATURES=SQL,AS,IS,Tools
/INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="MyDomain\MyAccount"
/SQLSVCPASSWORD="************" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="MyDomain\MyAccount "
/AGTSVCACCOUNT="MyDomain\MyAccount" /AGTSVCPASSWORD="************"
/ASSVCACCOUNT="MyDomain\MyAccount" /ASSVCPASSWORD="************"
/ISSVCAccount="MyDomain\MyAccount" /ISSVCPASSWORD="************"
/ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="MyDomain\MyAccount"

Press any key to exit...
```

Comment: Unfortunately MediaPath is not a valid parameter for my installer. Are you referring to the download installer? The one I have is the full offline installation for CORE (>200MB)

Comment: Yes, i was referring to the download-installer from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994

Comment: Added options shown from `SETUP.EXE /?`, after extraction.....